# How to get friends address using fbconnect in iPhone

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I want to know that is it possible to find locations of friends or address using fbconnect in iPhone, basically i got friendlist in my iPhone app, now i want to find the location of my friends which they have given in facebook. Is it possible to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the HackBook example in Facebook developers..Its useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

See the link and download http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/1744353455994565

firend Facebook user id = 1744353455994565

Comment: Facebook iOS sdk 3.0 released